# in TypeScript, how can I create an extensible generic type with children of the same type, with a default type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

At first, I have a type like this:

```js
type Foo = {
    bar: string;
    children: Foo[];
};
```

Now, I want to allow extending of the `Foo` type so users can add properties, but still provide at least `bar` and `children`. I figured I could easily do that:

```js
interface Foo<T extends Foo<T>> {
    bar: string;
    children: T[];
}
```

But then I tried to declare such a type... and I can't:
[image: requires 1 type arg]

It's an infinite loop...

So, I then try with a default generic type parameter, but then again, I can't...
[image: circular default]

Am I having a brain fart? or is this not doable?

I am trying to convey:

- the type `Foo` is extensible
- the type `Foo` has a `children` property of the same type as the type itself
- full type-safety (so no `any` anywhere - pun intended)

Answer (score 2):

Depends how you would like to extend Foo type. If you want to add and access properties ad hoc (at any time in the code), Foo must have a "string index signatures" in it's interface:

```
type Foo = {
    bar: string;
    children: Foo[];
    [key: string]: any; };

let fooInstance: Foo; 
fooInstance.bar = "toto"; 
fooInstance.newProperty = 24;
```

Vscode pic:

[image]

You can also extend Foo using other interfaces, via inheritance.

```
interface FooExtended extends Foo {
    age: number;
    street: string;
}

let extendedFoo : FooExtended;
extendedFoo.age = 22;
extendedFoo.bar = "popo";
```

You can override the interface, to match the children array with the new interface:

```
interface FooExtended extends Foo {
    age: number;
    street: string;
    children: FooExtended[];
}
```

Comment: I can see it _works_ but there is no intellisense or type-safety (the latter being the most important). Let me amend my question with this detail.
Could you elaborate on you elaborate on your _inheritance_ suggestion? I am a 20 year veteran so I know and quite understand inheritance, but what do you mean in this particular example?

Comment: Added.Check it out.

Comment: right, but now the type of your `children` property is still `Foo`, not `FooExtended`.

Comment: No problem. Check the solution again.

Answer (score 1):

You can add empty interface `JustFoo` to avoid infinity loop:

```
interface Foo<T> {
    bar: string;
    children: T[];
}

interface JustFoo extends Foo<JustFoo> {
}

interface Bar extends Foo<Bar> {
    barProp: number;
}

const bar: Bar = {
    barProp: 123,
    bar: 'aaa',
    children: [{ barProp: 123, bar: 'aaa', children: []}]
}

const foo: JustFoo = {
    bar: 'aaa',
    children: [{  bar: 'aaa', children: []}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright,
Thanks Lombas and aquz for pointing me in the right direction. As many times before, I tried to simplify my problem to share it here and in doing so, I oversimplified it.

My more accurate problem was the following structure:

```js
export type NavigationEntry = NavigationEntryWithChildren | NavigationEntryWithoutChildren;

interface NavigationEntryBase {
    display: string;
    exact?: boolean;
}
interface NavigationEntryWithChildren extends NavigationEntryBase {
    children: NavigationEntry[];
}

interface NavigationEntryWithoutChildren extends NavigationEntryBase {
    routerLinkInfo: any[] | string;
}
```

As the name indicates, this is about creating a *navigation* structure. At any level, either you have a URL (`routerLinkInfo`) *or* you have children. So, I had to use *union* types and not simply interfaces.

Though I have been doing TypeScript full time for 3 years, my mind sometimes gets stuck in the more traditional object-oriented type systems like C# and forgets that TypeScript will *just make it work*.

So, instead of fiddling with the `NavigationEntry` and making it work directly, I created a couple of extra types:

```js
interface CustomNavigationEntryWithChildren<T> extends NavigationEntryWithChildren {
    children: CustomNavigationEntry<T>[];
}

export type CustomNavigationEntry<T> =
    | (CustomNavigationEntryWithChildren<T> & T)
    | (NavigationEntryWithoutChildren & T);
```

Using this approach, all the existing code that only needed `NavigationEntry` will still work. And the newer projects that want to add extra properties on their navigation nodes can do it like this:

```js
type Foo = CustomNavigationEntry<{foo: boolean}>;
```

The above will require all nodes to have a `foo` boolean value.

Hope this helps the next person (even if it's just me ;) )